# InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using **Cloudera VM** for mapreduce pratice.

I just created the jar from the default `wordcount` classes given by cloudera.

I am getting this error when I run the mapreduce program. Can I know what I am missing?

```
InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set.
```

Answer (score 0):

To process data using MapReduce program you need-

1. Mapper class
2. Reducer class
3. Driver class(Main class to run MapReduce program)
4. Input data(path of input data to analysis)
5. Output directory(path of output directory,where output of the program will store, this
   directory should not already exist in HDFS)

From the error, It seems you have not set the output directory path. If output directory is not already set in your code, than you have to pass it at runtime if your code is accepting the argument for the same. [Here](http://www.javamakeuse.com/2016/01/hadoop-mapreduce-wordcount-tutorial.html) is a very good step-by-step guide to run first WordCount program in MapReduce.